# Apple Music download error "Too Many Devices"

Tags: itunes, apple-id, music, apple-music, music.app

I'm using Music.app (née iTunes) to play music on macOS with an active Apple Music streaming subscription.

When I press the "Download" button, I get the error:

[image: Too Many Devices]

> Too Many Devices
>
> To play offline content, you'll need to remove some devices from your account.

How can I view the current devices on my account? How can I remove a device?

How can I download Apple Music on this Mac?

Comment: I recommend contacting Apple Support. I've seen other people on twitter with this message as well and they may be better equipped to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can view connected devices in the Music app on macOS if you select `Account` and then `Show my account`. You will be asked to enter your account credentials and see some general information about your account. Under `Downloads and purchases` you will see the option to `manage devices`. If you click that you will see a list of connected devices and have the option to remove them.

Comment: Here's a link containing additional ways to find(and/or remove) iCloud's linked devices https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205064

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an article that should let you [remove devices one by one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205064) until you can play music.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074

> For any Service, you can have up to 10 devices (but only a maximum of 5 computers) signed in with your Apple ID at one time

Family accounts can stream to 6 devices, everyone else can only stream to one device at a time.

At the bottom of that page are customer support links if you feel you followed it and are still blocked from using the service on the documented number of devices. There could be some error on their end if you don’t have more than a couple devices signed in.